# Blender Material Listing in Woodworking

Tags: scripting

I am working as a designer at a woodworking company. I am making interior designs with Blender.
I just imagine that I could use a script to print the necessary materials for the job.

The method is simple.
I created a cube where X is the grain dimension Y is the 90 degree of grain and Z is the thickness (1.8mm in most scenarios). So my key numbers is the X and Y dimensions.

I used this cube to create carcasses (various types can be achieved with a few changes) and grouped these objects. Also I created a custom property for all panel which creates the whole carcasse (sides, top, bottom, shelf etc) called "Élfólia" (Edgebanding) where I use letters to indicate which side we need to edge-band:

'A' letter is always the x dimension 'B' is always the y dimension and also big 'A' means a different type of edge-banding (called ABS) than small 'a' (called PVC). This is true for letters 'B' as well.
This is the base.
I found a script which based on the selection (which is perfectly fine for my groups) and go through all objects then saves its X and Y dimension to a file. I want to extend this output with edge-banding and area measurements in m2.

Here is the script which I use now:

```
# import the necessary modules we need
# in our case, blender's python API and python's os module
import bpy, os

# get the current selection
selection = bpy.context.selected_objects

# initialize a blank result variable
result = ""


for sel in selection:
# adatok lekérdez

    dims = sel.dimensions
    # write the selected object's name and dimensions to a string
    result += "%.01f x %.01f - %s\n" % (dims.x*100, dims.y*100, sel.name)

# get path to render output (usually /tmp\)
tempFolder = os.path.abspath (bpy.context.scene.render.filepath)
# make a filename
filename = os.path.join (tempFolder, "Dimensions.txt")
# open a file to write to
file = open(filename, "w")
# write the data to file
file.write(result)
# close the file
file.close()
```

I want to extend this script with 3 things:

1st:
In the 'for' cycle
if (there is a custom property called "Élfólia") then
write "Élfólia" content to the end of actual line
else
simply jump in a new line

2nd.
Simple math
Make an area summary from all panels. (SumArea += sel.xdimension*sel.ydimension)
and write this to the end of the file

3rd. The trickiest
I should check if there is "Élfólia" and if there is then:
check for capital "A" and if there is then SumABS += number of "A"*x dimension
check for capital "B" and if there is then SumABS += number of "B"*y dimension
check for "a" letter and if there is then SumPVC += number of "a"*x dimension
check for "b" letter and if there is then SumPVC += number of "b"*y dimension
And of course I want to write the summary to the file.

A few examples of Custom Property(Élfólia)'s content: [AAB] or [Abb] or [ab] or [a]...and so on..you get the point.

I can write code for years now but I don't know python. It would be great if you guys could help me out. Its just 5 minutes of coding if you know the right syntax but it would be a great help for our entire company :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just started working with something like that =)
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/219328/woodwork-addon-for-blender